# Choosing only rows where one of the columns has a value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table.

```
ID    Number           Param1        Param2        Param3          Param4        Param 5
1      null             null          null          null            null         XTO10
2      null             null          null          KMC3            null         null
3      null             YUP           null          null            null         null
4      103              VB0           BJ0           KL9             null         null
5      null             FH1           null          null            null         null
6      103              VB0           BJ0           KL9             null         null
7      103             null           null          KL9             null         null
8      103             VB0            BJ0           KL9             AS1           AM
9      null            VB0            BJ0           KL9             AS1           AM
10     99              HS1            null          null            AS1           AM
```

How get?

Choosing only rows where one of the columns has a value.
Only one value.

```
ID    Number           Param1        Param2         Param3          Param4       Param 5
1      null             null          null          null            null         XTO10
2      null             null          null          KMC3            null         null
3      null             YUP           null          null            null         null
5      null             FH1           null          null            null         null
```

Comment: "Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product."  MS SQL 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the sum of each column being not null and return only rows where the total is 1

```
select *
from Table
where
Iif(number is null,0,1) +
Iif(param1 is null,0,1) +
Iif(param2 is null,0,1) +
Iif(param3 is null,0,1) +
Iif(param4 is null,0,1) +
Iif(param5 is null,0,1) =1
```

[Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bb0c2c/1)

Alternative using `case`

```
select *
from t
where
case when number is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when param1 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when param2 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when param3 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when param4 is null then 0 else 1 end +
case when param5 is null then 0 else 1 end=1
```

Comment: @Denis please explain what you mean? it is being used with 3 *parameters* and executes without error. [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql)

Comment: @Denis There is no syntax error in Sql Server, are you using a different RDBMS?

Comment: I use MS SQL 2012

Comment: @Denis I have added alternative syntax with `case`, does that work for you?

Comment: Great. I don't know why you had an error with `iif` I'm not aware it functions differently in 2012 however 2012 is no longer available on db<>fiddle so I cannot test it.

Comment: "Great. I don't know why you had an error with iif "Thank you!